# Is there a way to make the box-shadow not affect the adjacent td?

Tags: html, css

here is my html/css code:

```html
<style>
td{
  padding:30px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px lightgray;
}
</style>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td><td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>  
</table>
```

this produces the the folowing output

[image]

my question is: is there a way to make the box-shadow not affect the adjacent td?

here is the required output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using [`filter: drop-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/drop-shadow) on the `table` element. This way all solid child elements are treated as a whole to make a single instance of a shadow.

```css
table {
  /* to prevent "gaps" between cells */
  border-collapse: collapse; 
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 10px lightgray);
}

td {
  padding: 30px;
  /* child elements need to have a solid background in order to cast a shadow */
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But be aware it doesn't support `spread` option like `box-shadow` does, to achieve heavier shadows, you might want to add more shadow instances to the filter:

```css
filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 5px lightgray) drop-shadow(0px 0px 10px lightgray);
```

Answer (score 0):

@HaoWu's answer is excellent. Here is another approach.

Apply the box shadow to a pseudo-element and have a same stacking context for all `td`s so that you can push all the pseudo element behind all `td`s.

> This requires you to set the `--row` and `--col` CSS variables on each `td` element. You could also use javascript for setting them.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  --size: 50px;
}

tbody {
  position: relative;
}

td {
  position: absolute;
  width: var(--size);
  height: var(--size);
  background: white;
  
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  
  left: calc(var(--size) * var(--col));
  top: calc(var(--size) * var(--row));
}

td::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 5px lightgray;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="--row: 0; --col: 0;">1</td>
      <td style="--row: 0; --col: 1;">2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="--row: 1; --col: 0;">3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```